What is the use of spring boot Autoconfiguration annotation
I am new to spring boot. I have a very basic question about sprint boot auto configuration mechanism.
As i understand by the reading the doc, for spring boot to auto configure a bean in a library(jar), library provider has to annotate the class with @Autoconfiguration annotation and provide the auto configuration class name in file META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.import.
What i do not understand is, what is the need for both?
providing the auto configuration class in file META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.import and annotate the class with @Autoconfiguration.
What additional purpose @Autoconfiguration annotation serve?
If we are providing the auto configuration class name in import file, spring boot should assume it as auto configuration class and automatically configures the beans in it.

The @AutoConfiguration annotation and the META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.import file serve complementary purposes:
@AutoConfiguration: Marks a class for auto-configuration and contains the logic for conditional bean creation.
AutoConfiguration.import: Lists auto-configuration classes for centralized registration and discovery.

My question is, class in AutoConfiguration.import is meant for Auto configuration. so why the need to annotate it with @AutoConfiguration if it does not have any other purpose.
